# What does it mean "return a type that is compatible"?

Tags: java, overriding, abstract-class

I am newby to Java, so I am reading Java Head First. I have seen that when you have an abstract class with abstract methods, you should override these abstract methods in a concrete class which means **"create a non-abstract method in your class with the same method signature (name and arguments) and a return type that is compatible with the declared return type of the abstract method."**

I can clearly understand the first part about having the same signature (name and arguments), but I would like to have a clear explanation about ***a return type that is compatible with the declared return type of the abstract method.***

What exactly means a compatible type? Could somebody please provide an example? Is it like the return type should be the class or a subclass of the return type defined in the abstract method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the example below. The return type of the abstract function `model()` is `int`.

```
abstract class Bike{  
  abstract short model();  
}
```

- When you redefine this method in a concrete class which extends the abstract class `Bike`. The concrete class should have a method `model()` with the same method signature and a compatible return type.

> One return type is compatible with another, if it doesn't lead to loss
>   of precision.
>
> One return type compatible with `short` is `int`.

```
class Honda4 extends Bike{  
    int model() 
    //long is compatible with int since there is no loss of precision
    {
         return 1234;
    }  

    public static void main(String args[]){  
        Bike obj = new Honda4();  
        System.out.println(obj.model());  
    }  

}
```

Can you name a return type which is not compatible with `int` ?

- `short`. It may lead to loss of precision.

Comment: I think your explanation is clearer because you are using code which simplifies the understanding. Thank you @Matews Mathai

Comment: My pleasure. Happy Learning :)

Comment: And Head First Java is an amazing book. Complete reading it. It has turned me to what I am today. The whole Head First Series is Good.

Comment: Yeah! Although at the beginning I though I was learning nothing after chapter 6 I started loving it.

Comment: I don't know if this worked under Java 7 or below, but under both OpenJDK 8 and 11, the example code in this answer does not compile (`Honda4.java:2: error: model() in Honda4 cannot override model() in Bike: return type long is not compatible with int`).

Answer (score 4):

The type returned by the overriding method must be the same, or must be a subclass or subinterface of the type returned in the base method.

In short: it must respect the contract of the base method. If the base method says: "I return a Fruit", then the overriding method can say "I return a Fruit", but it can also say "I return a Banana".

That's fine because a Banana is a Fruit. Anyone calling the method and getting a Banana is happy: a fruit was expected, and a fruit was received.

Returning a Car isn't correct though, because when you ask for a Fruit, getting a Car is not acceptable.

The technical term for this is a [*covariant return type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type). Note that this rule is true even if the base class/method is not abstract.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. I was thinking about that, but I have not a deep understanding of subinterface yet.

Answer (score 4):

If your return type is `A`, then you can also return objects of any class `B` derived from `A`. All of these are compatible types.

Your return type can also be an interface. In this case, you can return *any object* that implements this interface.

Answer (score 1):

This means the your implementation of the abstract method must return the same or derivated class of the object defined in the Abstract class
example:
you have an abstractClass with abstract method

```
abstract class AbstractTest{
    abstract Date getInitialTime();
}
```

then you have a test class.

```
class Test extends AbstractTest{

...
    Date getInitialTime(){
        return new Date();
    }
}
```

you override the `getInitialTime` method and the return of that method must be an object of the class date or of a superclass of that

if you return something else, then you are breaking the contract between what the method of your class returns and what the method os the parent class returns...